# AOSP repo sync with a private repository

Tags: android, linux, github, repository

I have a private repository for one of the applications I'm using in the ROM I'm building.

Problem I'm having is I know of no way to input my GitHub credentials during repo sync.

Is it possible to use repo sync when one of the repositories is private (excluding manual sync)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in git's ability to store credentials.

Do `git config --global credentials.helper store`

Sync a repository from each URL manually, eg one GitHub.

After inputting the credentials the first time it'll never ask again!